# Server to handle tcp and udp connections at the same time in java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, tcp, udp

I am a beginning java programmer and I need to write a tpc/udp server that handle these request simultaneously. I have found researching this is that I will need to implement a thread for the tcp communications and a thread for the udp communications and don't know about threading. Any help with this project would be greatly appreciated even if it is just advise on the processes needed.

Comment: Network and multi-threading are very broad topics. Knowing how to use UDP in a reliable way is a career in itself.  I would limit the scope of what you are trying to do and use a library which supports these already to make your life a little easier. I would start with netty.

Comment: If you want to learn specifically about threads in the Java programming language, you should look at the Oracle tutorials:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/